# Represent a string of digits as days of the week

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 7 digit string of individual boolean values (e.g. `0010010`), each digit representing a day of the week, Sunday to Saturday. If the day is active it's flagged as `1`.

I want to check the string and output the abbreviated name of any days that are active.

**Examples**

`1000000` is converted to `Sun` because the digit for Sunday is active.

`0100010` is converted to `MonFri`

`1111111` is converted to `SunMonTueWedThuFriSatSun`

I am using a system someone else designed here. What is the simplest method to achieve this with PHP?

Comment: What exactly is a "7 digit boolean array"? What's a valid PHP representation of that?

Comment: So how you actually receiving this “boolean array” in PHP? `000000` as a string, or …?

Comment: Can more than one day be active? If it's only one day per entry, why not just store the number 1-7?

Comment: `(000000)` Either Monday or Sunday has already been lost. Is it time to panic now, or is this just the New Normal?

Answer (score 1):

I'll post this here, hoping that it may improve the question:

```
<?php

$dow =['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun'];
$day = '0010000';

$result = array_combine($dow, str_split($day));
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'mon' => '0',
  'tue' => '0',
  'wed' => '1',
  'thu' => '0',
  'fri' => '0',
  'sat' => '0',
  'sun' => '0',
)
```

Further with the additional information:

```
$day    = '1000100';
$result = array_combine($dow, str_split($day));
print implode(array_keys(array_filter($result)));
```

Output:

```
monfri
```